# Exporting Data from wpf listview Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listview

I am working on converting a GUI written in another language into a WPF project using VS 2017 (new to doing it this way). I have all of the controls created successfully, and the background code working, with the exception of the listview. The flow of the app is the end user fills in various fields, which populate the listview. Then the listview exports all content to a csv file. Below is how I set up the listview:

```
        <ListView x:Name="lstOut" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Margin="10,394,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1294">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="CPU" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CPU}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="RAM" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RAM}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="IP Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IP}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Subnet" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Subnet}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Port Group" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PortGroup}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Gateway" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Gateway}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="DNS" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DNS}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Template" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Template}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Host" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Host}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Site Code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Site}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Folder" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Folder}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="DataStore" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Datastore}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Patch Method" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Patch}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HDD1 Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD1Size}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HDD1 Format" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD1Format}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HDD2 Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD2Size}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HDD2 Format" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD2Format}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HDD3 Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD3Size}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HDD3 Format" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD3Format}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HDD4 Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD4Size}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HDD4 Format" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD4Format}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HDD5 Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD5Size}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="HDD5 Format" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD5Format}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I then created a class on the project to get and set the columns based on the data entered by the user:

```
    public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CPU { get; set; }
    public int RAM { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string Subnet { get; set; }
    public string PortGroup { get; set; }
    public string Gateway { get; set; }
    public string DNS { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Template { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string Folder { get; set; }
    public string Datastore { get; set; }
    public string Patch { get; set; }
    public int HDD1Size { get; set; }
    public string HDD1Format { get; set; }
    public int HDD2Size { get; set; }
    public string HDD2Format { get; set; }
    public int HDD3Size { get; set; }
    public string HDD3Format { get; set; }
    public int HDD4Size { get; set; }
    public string HDD4Format { get; set; }
    public int HDD5Size { get; set; }
    public string HDD5Format { get; set; }
}
```

To test this, under the main window initialization I added the following:

```
            this.lstOut.Items.Add(new MyItem {
            Name = "SPMASV-KL16SQD1", CPU = 4, RAM = 8192, IP = "10.10.40.79", Subnet = "255.255.252.0", PortGroup = "Server231",
            Gateway = "10.10.40.254", DNS = "10.10.40.69", Description = "Testing", Template = "OAK 2016 Template", Host = "LAX",
            Site = "LAX", Folder = "Servers", Datastore = "OakStorMagic", Patch = "Patch Reboot", HDD1Size = 320, HDD1Format = "Thick",
            HDD2Size = 200, HDD2Format = "Thin", HDD3Size = 60, HDD3Format = "Thick", HDD4Size = 500, HDD4Format = "Thin",
            HDD5Size = 1350, HDD5Format = "EagerZeroedThick"
        });
```

This populates the listview as I would expect. The problem comes in exporting the data once the user clicks the appropriate button. I have been looking at the ListView Class page on MSDN for an easy way to both read a single column, AND to export the entire contents as an array, but am not having any luck. I would think, the way I created it, I could either access the item structure through typical . notation (e.g. lstOut.Name) or convert all of it into an array and iterate through, but am not coming up with an easy way to do either.

Just looking for a nudge in the right direction, if anyone has any suggestions on an easy way to accomplish this. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take advantage of WPF binding system. Consider the following simple sample built from your code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpfTest="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">


    <Grid Background="DimGray" Name="Grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="lstOut" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="CPU" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CPU}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="RAM" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RAM}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="IP Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IP}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Subnet" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Subnet}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Port Group" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PortGroup}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Gateway" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Gateway}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="DNS" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DNS}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Template" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Template}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Host" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Host}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Site Code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Site}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Folder" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Folder}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="DataStore" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Datastore}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Patch Method" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Patch}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HDD1 Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD1Size}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HDD1 Format" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD1Format}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HDD2 Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD2Size}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HDD2 Format" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD2Format}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HDD3 Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD3Size}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HDD3 Format" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD3Format}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HDD4 Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD4Size}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HDD4 Format" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD4Format}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HDD5 Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD5Size}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="HDD5 Format" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HDD5Format}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Add new" Click="AddNew"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Export" Click="Export"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can see that the window's data context is set to itself, also you bind your listview's itemsource property to a collection which should be a property in your viewmodel (in this case since we are setting the datacontext to Self, the viewmodel is our window itself). Then in codebehind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddNew(null, null);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

        private void AddNew(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyItems.Add(new MyItem
            {
                Name = "SPMASV-KL16SQD1",
                CPU = 4,
                RAM = 8192,
                IP = "10.10.40.79",
                Subnet = "255.255.252.0",
                PortGroup = "Server231",
                Gateway = "10.10.40.254",
                DNS = "10.10.40.69",
                Description = "Testing",
                Template = "OAK 2016 Template",
                Host = "LAX",
                Site = "LAX",
                Folder = "Servers",
                Datastore = "OakStorMagic",
                Patch = "Patch Reboot",
                HDD1Size = 320,
                HDD1Format = "Thick",
                HDD2Size = 200,
                HDD2Format = "Thin",
                HDD3Size = 60,
                HDD3Format = "Thick",
                HDD4Size = 500,
                HDD4Format = "Thin",
                HDD5Size = 1350,
                HDD5Format = "EagerZeroedThick"
            });
        }

        private void Export(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var myItem in MyItems)
            {
                //do whatever you need to export your data...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you click the Export button you can iterate through your collection containing instances of your model, which is represented by MyItem class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, while this wasn't exactly what I was looking for it gave me a push in the right direction. I was able to figure out what I needed to do.